# Why do I need to "use grunt to build"?

Tags: svg, gruntjs, gulp, snap.svg, taskmanager

In this case I'm trying to use snap.svg[snap.svg library website](http://snapsvg.io/) to play around with svg manipulation. I've set up the library and it's running just fine so I don't understand why I need to use **grunt**, and what exactly it's **building**.

It should be mentioned that I just discovered task managing in the first place and I'm not 100% on what it does.

Comment: Did you read the GruntJS website? The first paragraphs sum it up pretty nicely. In one word: automation. It helps you with the repetitive tasks like minification, compilation, unit testing, linting, etc. But if you don't need those tasks, than you also don't need grunt. Building is doing all those repetitive tasks.

Comment: @allcaps I did read some of the documentation. I guess I was just confused about whether or not it was required or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt takes away lots of pain when you are working on high performance projects. Grunt is the JavaScript task runner. While developing any project we need to performing repetitive tasks and these all repetitive tasks will become automation by using gruntjs.

1. Image optimization - images
2. minifies - Js,css and SVG files
3. Concatenation - adding more then one files to one single file
4. Compile SASS - compiles SASS to css
5. Watch - Watches over specific files

Many more benefits...

Comment: a friend of mine mentioned that you could use grunt or gulp as a functional backend. Is this true?